# Access violation reading location in UDP socket recvfrom

Tags: c++, udp

I am trying to get a data block(800 bytes) several times from the client. Before i was trying to get data blocks without prefix length information but then i started to sent data blocks with prefix length information of data block to the server.

In both case i received data block only once on the server side. By debugging my server side i observed that when my `while(1)` loop try to execute second time, i get a debug error says

```
First-chance exception at 0x012e2e53 in UDP_server.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xbd63841d.
Unhandled exception at 0x012e2e53 in UDP_server.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xbd63841d.
```

I have tried lot of things my own but still not able to figure out whats the matter.

// Server code

```
int total_bytes = 0;
    int bytes_recv=0;
    int count = 0;
    uint32_t  nlength =0;
    std::vector<double> m_vector(nlength/sizeof(double));
    int length_received;
    while(1)
    {
     //code to received data length from the client
        length_received = recvfrom(Socket,(char*)&nlength, 4, 0,(SOCKADDR*)&ClientAddr,&i); 
        m_vector.resize(nlength/sizeof(double));

        //code to received data length from the client
        int bytes_recv = recvfrom(Socket,(char*)&m_vector,nlength,0,(SOCKADDR*)&ClientAddr,&i);
        count++;

       if((bytes_recv > 0 ))
        {
            total_bytes = total_bytes+bytes_recv;
            std::cout<<"Server: loop counter is"<<count<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"Server: Received bytes are"<<total_bytes<<std::endl;
        }else
        {
            std::cout<<"Data Receiving has finished"<<std::endl;
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try this `(char*)&m_vector[0]`.

Comment: @Nick: Thanks for catching the error, now i am using  ` m_vector.data()` and your suggestion working nice as well!

Comment: @Nick POSIX `recvfrom` accepts `void*`, I guess one has to cast it to `char*` on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(char*)&m_vector` is not correct. To cast a vector to an array correctly do:

```
&m_vector[0]
```

or

```
&*m_vector.begin()
```

or

```
&m_vector.front()
```

or, in C++11:

```
m_vector.data()
```

---

On Windows you may also need to cast the expression to `char*` because [Windows `recvfrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) takes a `char*` buffer, not `void*`.